# Changing computer's IP address through terminal python?

Tags: networking, https, proxy, ip

I am working on a python program on my Mac.

I am wondering if there's a way to change a web proxy without accessing system preferences.

So far, I have tried

```
export http_proxy=http://216.56.48.118:8080/
```

Is there any way to type in a terminal and set a computer's web proxy? (Should be repeatable)

Comment: It would be good to clarify your aim here, because "proxy" and "computer's IP address" are very different things.  What is your end goal?

Comment: Note that, even if you're connecting to your local network through a proxy, your external IP address will not change because it's the NAT IP address of the router.

Comment: I am trying to set IP web proxies. But, the observed IP address is supposed to change on that lookup site.

Comment: I think you're confusing proxies with VPNs

Comment: Can you answer the question Harshith?

Comment: "_I am trying to set IP web proxies. But, the observed IP address is supposed to change on that lookup site._" No, it's not. Changing the proxy server used by a host has nothing to do with what the public IP address assigned to a router is.